# Input-group на гридах

Tags: css, css-grid

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли такое сделать на гридах? Если есть референсы буду благодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка

```
<label class="string"> 
   <div class="string__prepend">
      @
    </div>
    <div class="string__append">
      @
    </div>
    <input class="string__control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Плейсхолдер"> 
    <span class="string__label">Лейбл</span>
</label>
```

Код из 3го примера
Важно что бы string__label шел последний, но перед ним было текстовое поле.
Так же важно что бы prepend и append были резиновыми

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного классы поменял, для удобства.

```css
.string {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "label . ."
    "prepend control append";
}

.string__sym {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 2.5vw;
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.string__sym_prepend {
  grid-area: prepend;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.string__sym_append {
  grid-area: append;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.string__control {
  grid-area: control;
  padding: 1.5vh 1vw;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="string"> 
   <div class="string__sym string__sym_prepend">
      @
    </div>
    <div class="string__sym string__sym_append">
      @
    </div>
    <input class="string__control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Плейсхолдер"> 
    <span class="string__label">Лейбл</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо большое. Тока есть чуток проблема, добавил автопрефиксоры и проверил в IE11, в случае когда нету append input растягивается, а если нету prepend, то у инпута есть оступ( и он не растягивается( Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов так какое поведение нужно? Если нужно, чтобы инпут растягивался влево, когда элемента `prepend` вообще нету, то так сделать по моему нельзя(с этой разметкой естественно).

Comment: а с какой можно будет?
А почему когда нету append'a он растягивается?
Конечном итоге нужно, что бы кнопка растягивалась даже когда нету `append` и `prepend`

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов потому что левую колонку занимает ещё и label

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов в смысле левую колонку занимает ещё и `label`, поэтому влево `input` не растягивается

Comment: @АзаматШарафутдинов `label` нужно убрать за grid-контейнер

Comment: @h Спасибо большое